# `man` not respecting `MANPAGER` unless it's invoked explicitly

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, pager, manpage

I'm on Mac OS, using GNU Bash and GNU man-db, and I have my `MANPAGER` set to `most`.

```
$ uname
Darwin
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)
...
$ man --version
man 2.8.5
$ echo $MANPAGER
most
```

When I invoke `man ls`, I see that `man` does not respect my `MANPAGER`.

[image: Invoke as <code>man ls</code> does not use <code>most</code>]

But when I invoke `MANPAGER=most man ls`, `man` uses `most` to show the manual page.

[image: Invoke as <code>MANPAGER=most man ls</code> uses <code>most</code>]

(1) What's going on to keep `man` from seeing/using my `MANPAGE` environment variable. I'm at a loss for how to explain this observed behavior.

(2) How can I get `man ls` to see/use my `MANPAGE` environment variable, so that I can simply invoke as `man ls` and don't have to invoke as `MANPAGE=most man ls`.

Comment: It is possiblming missing the environment variable to be exported: `export MANPAGER=most`

Comment: That was it. I'm so sorry, everyone <.<;

Comment: BTW, in the future, you can detect this using `declare -p MANPAGER`. If it says `declare -- MANPAGER` then it's a regular non-exported shell variable; if it says `set -x MANPAGER`, then it's an environment variable available to all subprocesses the shell runs.

Comment: BTW, in the future, questions about configuring your shell for interactive use are a better fit for our sister site [unix.se]; interactive shell configuration is done by people who aren't developers, whereas Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions "unique to software development".

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with `man` specifically, I just wasn't exporting my environment variables in `.profile`. For whatever reason, I didn't think `export` was needed for variables defined in `.profile`. Changing the line `MANPAGER=man` to `export MANPAGER=man` fixed my problem.

Comment: If you want to avoid the need to add the explicit `export`, use `set -a` at the top of your `.profile` to turn on auto-export, and `set +a` at the bottom to turn it back off. (You want it off most of the time, because environment space is a limited resource; the same kernel-allocated per-process memory region is also used for command-line arguments, so the more and larger variables you export, the shorter your maximum command line length can be).